# Firebase UI from hosting URL's

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebaseui, stenciljs

I am using Firebase from hosting URL's and want to add firebase UI in a similar way.

I installed both libraries via npm and have the following code in my index file.

```
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/8.2.7/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/8.2.7/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/8.2.7/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/8.2.7/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/8.2.7/firebase-functions.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/8.2.7/firebase-storage.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Firebase -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

It seems to work all the firebase libraries but I also want to include firebase UI for authentication so I don't (initially) need to build the login layout myself.

I cannot seem to find any example where firebase UI can also (locally) be included via the index file.

Is there anyone that has some experience including firebase UI in the simplest way possible without imports in javascript files?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at the [documentation for Firebase UI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui).